# Intermittent hang on S3 GetObjectAsync when called from Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that is triggered by an `ObjectCreated` event on an S3 bucket.  The process is such that a new file gets placed in the bucket, triggering the Lambda function to fire.  The Lambda reads that file from S3 and does some processing on it.  I am using a common `AmazonS3Client` that is spun up when the Lambda starts so that the client should be shared across executions.

I am experiencing an issue where it appears that the `GetObjectAsync` call to retrieve the S3 object intermittently hangs.  Basically I was experiencing my lambda function timing out at it's max allowed duration.  I've bumped that up from 30 seconds to 60 seconds to now 300 seconds, and still seeing the intermittent function timeouts.  I added some debugging logs and have narrowed it down to this:

```
LogMessage($"[GetS3File:GetObjectAsync]: {s3Bucket} | {remoteFileName}");

var re = await _s3Client.GetObjectAsync(s3Bucket, remoteFileName);

LogMessage($"[GetS3File:GetObjectAsync]: {s3Bucket} | {remoteFileName} | Finished");
```

When the lambda function times out, my logs show the first LogMessage statement, but not the second, implying it's making the `GetObjectAsync` call but never coming out of it. I tried fiddling with the timeout settings:

```
// Adjust timeout settings based on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/
            var s3Config = new AmazonS3Config() { 
                RegionEndpoint = _region,
                MaxErrorRetry = 3, // number of retries
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) // new connection timeout
            };
```

but that does not appear to have helped - in fact, I don't seem to be seeing any sort of client retry or connection timeout reported from the S3 client, or at least it's not being logged.  That makes me wonder if it's not a connection timeout at all?

This process appears to overall work as expected - the vast majority of the function calls are successful.  But I'm seeing it enough that I want to chase down why and how to fix it. I've run across mentions of VPC configurations affecting Lambda-S3 connectivity, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.  My Lambda has no VPC configuration, and it's able to interact with the S3 bucket normally in almost all cases.

Is there any other reasons I should look at to what's happening here, or is there other debugging or error capturing I can add to get a better insight into what's going on with the `GetObjectAsync` call?

Edit: So after some further analysis, it looks like what I am experiencing is that a file is uploaded to S3 and my lambda is trigger and processes the file successfully.  However, it looks like I am seeing the lambda function trigger again, some number of minutes later, attempting to process the same file.  The second invocation is a different RequestID than the first, but I do see the second invocation's RequestID multiple times, I'm assuming because of Lambda's retries since it times out.  I still haven't figured out 1) why it's firing a second time, usually minutes after the file has processed, and 2) even assuming it fires because of extra events firing, why does it hang on `GetObjectAsync` if the file is presumably not there, vs just coming back as null because the object no longer exists.

Comment: I'm going to guess that you are using .net framework, and you need `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on the `GetObjectAsync`.

Comment: Yes....yes, I'm using .net core and C#.  Thanks for the advice, I'll try adding that!  Is there documentation somewhere explaining why that is necessary?

Comment: Following up....I added `.ConfigureAwait(false)` last night, and overnight it seems to have performed better, but I'm going to watch it during the day.  However, I *did* log the same issue occurring once, even with `.ConfigureAwait(false)` added.  So maybe the overnight behavior was just coincidence?   Can number of lambda invocations affect calls to other AWS services?

Comment: Another update....I'm still seeing the same issue, even after adding `ConfigureAwait(false)`.  That does not appear to have made a difference.

Is there something I should be looking for to try and capture the state of `GetObjectAsync`?

Comment: The ConfigureAwait thing is not an issue with .net core (it's really just a framework thing).  It still sounds like a deadlock though.

Comment: Hmmmm well I'm actually using .NET Core 2.1 for the lambda code anyway....so maybe I'm back to the drawing board.  I'll see if I can find some ways to test for a deadlock, though.

Comment: Ah!  Your deadlock comment made me check something....so I'm seeing multiple `GetObjectAsync` calls for the same S3 object...so yeah, it looks like when a file is dropped it triggers the lambda as it should, which starts processing the file....but then another invocation attempts to process that same file?  The end of the process deletes it so I bet the file is gone during or before the 2nd invocation tries to get it. Now to see why ObjectCreated is triggering multiple invocations...